# Display Label and Progressbar into combo box

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have this code which is used to display text into combo box.

```
ProgressBar pb1 = new ProgressBar(0.6);
        ProgressIndicator pi1 = new ProgressIndicator(0.6);
        VBox vb1 = new VBox();
        vb1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Progressbar 1"), pi1);

        ProgressBar pb2 = new ProgressBar(0.6);
        ProgressIndicator pi2 = new ProgressIndicator(0.6);
        VBox vb2 = new VBox();
        vb2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Progressbar 2"), pi2);

        ProgressBar pb3 = new ProgressBar(0.6);
        ProgressIndicator pi3 = new ProgressIndicator(0.6);
        VBox vb3 = new VBox();
        vb3.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Progressbar 3"), pi3);


        TextChooser textChooser = new TextChooser(
            vb1, vb2, vb3
        );

        textChooser.setStyle("-fx-font: 10px \"Verdana\";");

        VBox layout = new VBox(textChooser);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(22, 22, 22, 22));



public static class TextChooser extends StackPane {
        private Label label = new Label();
        private ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();

        public TextChooser(String... options) {
            StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            StackPane.setAlignment(combo, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            label.textProperty().bind(
                combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
            );
            label.visibleProperty().bind(
                combo.visibleProperty().not()
            );
            label.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));

            combo.getItems().setAll(options);
            combo.getSelectionModel().select(0);
            combo.setVisible(false);

            label.setOnMouseEntered(event -> combo.setVisible(true));
            combo.showingProperty().addListener(observable -> {
                if (!combo.isShowing()) {
                    combo.setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            combo.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
                if (!combo.isShowing()) {
                    combo.setVisible(false);
                }
            });

            getChildren().setAll(label, combo);
        }
    }
```

In my case I cannot insert VBox into the combo box. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Is the problem that you can not insert it or that the progress bars get removed whenever you select them? Also, check your TextChooser constructor. It is taking in Strings, while you are passing in VBoxes.

Comment: Yes I cannot insert VBox into the combo box.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to achieve, or any screenshot of that ?

Comment: Are you getting a compiler warning on this line: `TextChooser textChooser = new TextChooser(
            vb1, vb2, vb3
        );`?

Comment: No I get error in Netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is trying to construct a `TextChooser` using `VBox`es when the formal parameters are `String`s. Change your constructor to `public TextChooser(VBox... options)` and the `ComboBox` declaration to `private ComboBox<VBox> combo = new ComboBox<>();`.

Now you will be able to add the items to the combo box, and if it works, you are done. If you experience the issue with adding `Node`s to a `ComboBox`, you may want to add more code. The problem and solution are described in the Javadoc for `ComboBox`: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html. To get around the fact that the item you select will be removed from the combo box, you need to change this code (taken from the javadoc):

```
combo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<VBox>, ListCell<VBox>>() {
    @Override public ListCell<VBox> call(ListView<VBox> p) {
        return new ListCell<VBox>() {
            @Override protected void updateItem(VBox item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(item);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

after the line `getItems().setAll(options);`.

This is what your full example code would turn into:

```
    ProgressBar pb1 = new ProgressBar(0.6);
    ProgressIndicator pi1 = new ProgressIndicator(0.6);
    VBox vb1 = new VBox();
    vb1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Progressbar 1"), pi1);

    ProgressBar pb2 = new ProgressBar(0.6);
    ProgressIndicator pi2 = new ProgressIndicator(0.6);
    VBox vb2 = new VBox();
    vb2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Progressbar 2"), pi2);

    ProgressBar pb3 = new ProgressBar(0.6);
    ProgressIndicator pi3 = new ProgressIndicator(0.6);
    VBox vb3 = new VBox();
    vb3.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Progressbar 3"), pi3);


    TextChooser textChooser = new TextChooser(
        vb1, vb2, vb3
    );

    textChooser.setStyle("-fx-font: 10px \"Verdana\";");

    VBox layout = new VBox(textChooser);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(22, 22, 22, 22));



public static class TextChooser extends StackPane {
    private Label label = new Label();
    private ComboBox<VBox> combo = new ComboBox<>();

    public TextChooser(VBox... options) {
        StackPane.setAlignment(label, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        StackPane.setAlignment(combo, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        label.textProperty().bind(
            combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        );
        label.visibleProperty().bind(
            combo.visibleProperty().not()
        );
        label.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));

        combo.getItems().setAll(options);

        // vvvv Begin Optional Part vvvv
        combo.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<VBox>, ListCell<VBox>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<VBox> call(ListView<VBox> p) {
                return new ListCell<VBox>() {
                    @Override protected void updateItem(VBox item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);

                        if (item == null || empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(item);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        // ^^^^ End Optional Part ^^^^

        combo.getSelectionModel().select(0);
        combo.setVisible(false);

        label.setOnMouseEntered(event -> combo.setVisible(true));
        combo.showingProperty().addListener(observable -> {
            if (!combo.isShowing()) {
                combo.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        combo.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            if (!combo.isShowing()) {
                combo.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        getChildren().setAll(label, combo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you go. Hope that helps.

Comment: Are you sure because I get this error: `method javafx.collections.ObservableList.setAll(java.lang.String...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; javafx.scene.layout.VBox[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
    method javafx.collections.ObservableList.setAll(java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.String>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; javafx.scene.layout.VBox[] cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.String>)`? at line combo.getItems().setAll(options);

Comment: I need to set the combobox to `private ComboBox<VBoX> combo = new ComboBox<>();` but then I get error at this line: combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()

Comment: If you have to have something besides Strings in your ComboBox, you may need to implement your own selection model. Let me check on that. In the meantime, I updated the code some.

Comment: Also, what error? You should post those, otherwise it is hard to debug.

Comment: Yes the selection model is the problem. The code works when I use this: `combo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().asString()` but the result is just numbers. How I can display the progress bar properly? How I can create a custom selection model?

Comment: Please follow this discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518329/combobox-with-progress-bars-is-not-working-properly