# Managing a ComboBox items in JavaFX

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I'm populating a ComboBox using Text objects. Using Text objects rather than Strings allows me  to add an id value that I can use in my program and later exploit when I decide to internationalize the UI. Anyway, here is what I'm doing:
Main class:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    try {
        AnchorPane paneMain = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Test.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(paneMain);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Controller:

```
public class Test implements Initializable{

@FXML
private AnchorPane anchorPane;
@FXML
private ComboBox<Text> comboTime; 
private Text days;
private Text hours;
private Text minutes;
private int timeMultiplier; 

public Test(){
    days = new Text("Days");
    days.setId("86400000");
    hours = new Text("Hours");
    hours.setId("3600000");
    minutes = new Text("Minutes");
    minutes.setId("3600000");
    timeMultiplier = 0;
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    comboTime.getItems().removeAll(comboTime.getItems());
    comboTime.getItems().addAll(days, hours, minutes);
    comboTime.getSelectionModel().select(hours);

}

@FXML
private void setTimeMultiplier(){
    Text text = comboTime.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    timeMultiplier = Integer.valueOf(text.getId());
}

}
```

Test.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="anchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="100.99990000000253" prefWidth="94.99990000000253" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.spacitron.backupp.ui.controllers.Test">
  <children>
    <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="41.0" layoutY="224.0" prefWidth="216.0" spacing="5.0" />
    <ComboBox id="comboInterval" fx:id="comboTime" editable="false" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#setTimeMultiplier">
      <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="Item 1" />
          <String fx:value="Item 2" />
          <String fx:value="Item 3" />
        </FXCollections>
      </items>
    </ComboBox>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Now, this works just fine. The problem however is that when I select an item the text on that item goes blank like so:

[image]

And if I select another one, that disappears too:

[image]

I can still select the items, but they're just not there to be seen. Is this a bug and if so is there a way around it?

EDITED to provide MCVE

Comment: If you post an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve people could try it out on their machines for you.

Comment: I've had a look at the documentation for ComboBox (which was only added in JavaFx2.1+ so I can't test your code (sorry). But it has a warning at the start that you shouldn't add instance nodes directly, but should use a cell factory to create your instances: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html I'm not sure if this is going to be of any use to you, but give it a shot and see.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be putting the Text nodes into the ComboBox ... please see this question that will help you: [setButtonCell for ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20604974/3110608)